# Non existing subdomains getting indexed in google ?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

On my site `example.com`, there are no such domains as `www2.example.com`, `ww4.example.com` but google search is showing such pages.

Apparently the site do have such pages (duplicate of `example.com`) so how to stop this ? it looks to be some `http` access problem

Comment: @SMK - for future reference, code tags should be used for `code`, bold or something else should be used for **emphasis**

Answer (score 0):

You can use htacces to generate 403 or 404 for those subdomains, this will make google delete it from his index (it may take a little time) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ww(w2|4)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule . - [F] # will generate 403 forbidden
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, I really don't know how many such sub domains are there as for any random string, xxx.example.com, the sub domain is being shown